# Trigger.io doesn't set the correct landscape orientation

Tags: trigger.io

I have my app forced to be in portrait mode. There are only a few instances where I want to be able to show the app in landscape mode. I have this working but on a physical device [`forge.display.forceLandscape`](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/modules/display.html#forgedisplayforcelandscapesuccess-error) doesn't set the correct landscape mode (either landscape right or landscape left). The result I get is if I try to move the device from landscape left -> portrait -> landscape right, the screen is upside down.

This all works fine in the simulator.

Is there a way I can force a specific landscape orientation?

Comment: What devices and OS versions are you testing on here? Could you include snippets? I've tried a basic app and am getting expected behaviour: when limited to landscape, the display still rotates 180˚ when the device is turned that way. Checked on iOS 6.1 and Android 4.3.

Comment: We haven't been able to test this again since our plugins are broken due to the 2.0 update. Waiting for your reply to our emails...

Comment: Also are you testing from a physical device? I'm only able to see this error on a device. It works as expected in the simulator.